# Child div not over-riding parent div in css

Tags: css, html

Currently, my page's content header looks like this:
[image: Unwanted Style of web page]

But I would like the contents to look something like this:
[image: Wanted Style of web page]

Here's the HTML involving that portion of the page:

```
<div class="header">My Tools<a href="#possess" class="anchor_link">View Tools you Possess</a></div>
```

And my CSS for the involved classes:

```
#content .header{
    font-size:180%;
    width:1000px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}

#content .header .anchor_link{
    font-size:100%;
    text-align:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0059FF;
}
```

Can you explain what I'm doing wrong here, so that I can get by desired appearance?

### EDIT: Also, why won't the text in the anchor go to 100% instead of 180%

For future reference: I solved the font-size problem, because the 100% is in reference to the parent div, so to make this text smaller, I changed the anchor's font-size to 60%

Comment: Use `float: right;` for anchor ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
#content .header .anchor_link{
    text-align:right;
}
```

to

```
#content .header .anchor_link{
    float:right;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8jDD/)

Comment: jsfiddle.net is really neat, I've never seen it before. Also your code works perfect, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As everybody has mentioned, you have to use `float:right;` on the anchor link, the reason that `text-align: right;` didn't worked is `<a>` is a an inline element, hence its white space area doesn't stretches like a block level element for e.g. `<p>, <div>`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the reason behind it, I'm pretty new to web-development.

Answer (score 1):

Use `float:right`

try this:

```
#content .header .anchor_link{
    font-size:100%;
    float:right;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#0059FF;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Qr4N7/)

Answer (score 1):

About `font-size` you can't override parent properties so wrap MyTools in `<span>` like below, here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/2k8mb/)

```
<div class="header"><span>My Tools</span><a href="#possess" class="anchor_link">View Tools you Possess</a></div>


.header {
  width:600px;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
}

.header .anchor_link {
  font-size:100%;
  float:right;
  margin-top:14px;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#0059FF;
}

.header span {
  font-size:180%;
}
```